# why does unittest not treat a numpy array to as a sequence?

Tags: python, numpy, unit-testing

The following test fails:

```
import unittest
unittest.TestCase().assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],np.array([1.,2.,3.]))
```

I expected it to succeed. I understand that the problem is that `seq1 == seq2` returns a boolean ndarray when either seq is an ndarray, but I would expect `unittest` to be alert to such possibilities in the following sense: it should only rely on features of a `collections.abc.Sequence`. What is the justification for this behavior?

I am *not* asking for a workaround, which obviously just requires converting the ndarray to another sequence type.

**Edit:**

Most of the responses so far seem to miss the key issue. A test named `assertSequenceEqual` should, one would think, work for **any sequence**. To know what a sequence is, see the [glossary definition](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) and then `collections.abc`. Note the absence of a requirement even in the latter that `__eq__` be defined.

Comment: I'm not sure why `unittest` (which is a first-party library) should account for the behavior of third-party libraries like `numpy`.

Comment: Why do you expect unittest to know how to test equality for third party library objects? What would be a justification to add support for this particular library and not for hundreds of others?

Comment: There's an argument to be made that `__eq__` *should* be required to return a single Boolean value, rather than an element-wise comparison. This would not be the only part of the language definition designed to accommodate Numpy.

Comment: Maybe this question should be closed as outside of the normal scope of SO.  It's a opinion `why` question.  We can attempt to explain what is happening based on the code, but we can't explain why developers (Python or numpy) didn't go the extra mile and make the behavior conform to your expectations.

Comment: @hpaulj It is definitely not a `numpy` issue, where the behavior is exactly as documented. The issue is that `assertSequenceEqual` fails on two sequences (by the `collections.abc` definition) that are elementwise equal. Nonspeculative answers could include things like: there is additional relevant documentation at xxx, or it is an acknowledged oversight as documented at yyy, or it is a pragmatic decision based on speed as seen in conversation zzz. Additionally, one might point to a clear statement the intended behavior that indicates this is a bug.

Comment: The furthest that `ndarray` gets in the `collections.abc` hierarchy is `Collection`.  It's not `Reversible` or `Sequence`.  Regardless of how we interpret words like `sequence`, the fact of the matter is that this assertion uses a plain `==` test in an `if` context.  Single element arrays do work in this assertion.

Comment: I can see the argument that `assertSequenceEqual` should not rely on `==` since `==` is not a part of a sequences interface. Even if `ndarray` is not a sequence, it wouldn't be hard to define an object that adheres to being a sequence in every way but `assertSequenceEqual` still fails for.

Answer (score 3):

Numpy arrays have different equality semantics than Python sequences; in Numpy, equality is computed elementwise. For example:

```python
>>> [1, 2, 3] == [1, 2, 3]
True

>>> np.array([1, 2, 3]) == [1, 2, 3]
array([ True,  True,  True])
```

This breaks the assumptions made by `assertSequenceEqual`, which causes the test to fail.

For testing equality of numpy arrays, you should prefer utilities like [`numpy.testing.assert_array_equal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html):

```python
>>> np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.array([1, 2, 3]), [1, 2, 3])
```

Answer (score 2):

I may be giving this more attention than it's worth, but am curious about how the assert works.

(From development work on another builtin package, `argparse` I know that documentation is never exact.  There are nuances to the code that can't be captured in the documentation.  Documentation has to balance usefulness for most users, against the expectations of more pickier users.)

Here's the full code for this method:

```
Signature: M.assertSequenceEqual(seq1, seq2, msg=None, seq_type=None)
Source:   
    def assertSequenceEqual(self, seq1, seq2, msg=None, seq_type=None):
        """An equality assertion for ordered sequences (like lists and tuples).

        For the purposes of this function, a valid ordered sequence type is one
        which can be indexed, has a length, and has an equality operator.

        Args:
            seq1: The first sequence to compare.
            seq2: The second sequence to compare.
            seq_type: The expected datatype of the sequences, or None if no
                    datatype should be enforced.
            msg: Optional message to use on failure instead of a list of
                    differences.
```

**For the purposes of this function, a valid ordered sequence type is one
which can be indexed, has a length, and has an equality operator.**

`ndarray` has an equality operator, but `numpy` doesn't allow it to be used in an `if` statement.

```
        """
        if seq_type is not None:
            seq_type_name = seq_type.__name__
            if not isinstance(seq1, seq_type):
                raise self.failureException('First sequence is not a %s: %s'
                                        % (seq_type_name, safe_repr(seq1)))
            if not isinstance(seq2, seq_type):
                raise self.failureException('Second sequence is not a %s: %s'
                                        % (seq_type_name, safe_repr(seq2)))
        else:
            seq_type_name = "sequence"

        differing = None
        try:
            len1 = len(seq1)
        except (TypeError, NotImplementedError):
            differing = 'First %s has no length.    Non-sequence?' % (
                    seq_type_name)

        if differing is None:
            if seq1 == seq2:
                return
```

This is the step where `numpy` throws its error.  For the builtin sequence types like `list` and `string` this is a perfectly good expression.  I suppose they could have wrapped it in a `try/except ValueError`.  But is it up to the core python to anticipate all the ways that an external library would fail, or should the library itself take care to provide its own useful tests?

The rest of the code tries to identify how the sequences differ, whether in length, or element values.

```
            differing = '%ss differ: %s != %s\n' % (
                    (seq_type_name.capitalize(),) +
                    _common_shorten_repr(seq1, seq2))

            for i in range(min(len1, len2)):
                try:
                    item1 = seq1[i]
                except (TypeError, IndexError, NotImplementedError):
                    differing += ('\nUnable to index element %d of first %s\n' %
                                 (i, seq_type_name))
                    break

                try:
                    item2 = seq2[i]
                except (TypeError, IndexError, NotImplementedError):
                    differing += ('\nUnable to index element %d of second %s\n' %
                                 (i, seq_type_name))
                    break

                if item1 != item2:
                    differing += ('\nFirst differing element %d:\n%s\n%s\n' %
                                 ((i,) + _common_shorten_repr(item1, item2)))
                    break
            else:
                if (len1 == len2 and seq_type is None and
                    type(seq1) != type(seq2)):
                    # The sequences are the same, but have differing types.
                    return

            if len1 > len2:
                differing += ('\nFirst %s contains %d additional '
                             'elements.\n' % (seq_type_name, len1 - len2))
                try:
                    differing += ('First extra element %d:\n%s\n' %
                                  (len2, safe_repr(seq1[len2])))
                except (TypeError, IndexError, NotImplementedError):
                    differing += ('Unable to index element %d '
                                  'of first %s\n' % (len2, seq_type_name))
            elif len1 < len2:
                differing += ('\nSecond %s contains %d additional '
                             'elements.\n' % (seq_type_name, len2 - len1))
                try:
                    differing += ('First extra element %d:\n%s\n' %
                                  (len1, safe_repr(seq2[len1])))
                except (TypeError, IndexError, NotImplementedError):
                    differing += ('Unable to index element %d '
                                  'of second %s\n' % (len1, seq_type_name))
        standardMsg = differing
        diffMsg = '\n' + '\n'.join(
            difflib.ndiff(pprint.pformat(seq1).splitlines(),
                          pprint.pformat(seq2).splitlines()))

        standardMsg = self._truncateMessage(standardMsg, diffMsg)
        msg = self._formatMessage(msg, standardMsg)
        self.fail(msg)
File:      /usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py
```

That difference diagnosis is designed to work with sequences like lists, objects which have a `len` and element wise iteration makes sense.

Samples with lists:

```
In [309]: M.assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],[1., 2., 3.])
In [310]: M.assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],[1., 2., 4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-310-3cc2193995b9>", line 1, in <module>
    M.assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],[1., 2., 4])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 1100, in assertSequenceEqual
    self.fail(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 753, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Sequences differ: [1, 2, 3] != [1.0, 2.0, 4]

First differing element 2:
3
4

- [1, 2, 3]
+ [1.0, 2.0, 4]

In [311]: M.assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3,0],[1., 2., 4])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-311-1a7c548c65ee>", line 1, in <module>
    M.assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3,0],[1., 2., 4])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 1100, in assertSequenceEqual
    self.fail(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 753, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Sequences differ: [1, 2, 3, 0] != [1.0, 2.0, 4]

First differing element 2:
3
4

First sequence contains 1 additional elements.
First extra element 3:
0

- [1, 2, 3, 0]
+ [1.0, 2.0, 4]
```

For lists within lists:

```
In [314]: M.assertSequenceEqual([[1,2,3]],[[1,2,4]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-314-e71a55865cae>", line 1, in <module>
    M.assertSequenceEqual([[1,2,3]],[[1,2,4]])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 1100, in assertSequenceEqual
    self.fail(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 753, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Sequences differ: [[1, 2, 3]] != [[1, 2, 4]]

First differing element 0:
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]

- [[1, 2, 3]]
?         ^

+ [[1, 2, 4]]
?         ^
```

Without getting into the details, it's not clear that the diagnostic steps would handle numpy arrays any better.  `len` for an array is just the size of the first dimension.

Contrast that with the error reported by `numpy` own tester.  Why force `unittest` to work with arrays, when `numpy` provides a tester that's better suited to multidimensional arrays?

```
In [319]: numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal([[1,2,3]],[[1,2,4]])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-319-9392a2140ddd>", line 1, in <module>
    numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal([[1,2,3]],[[1,2,4]])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 1042, in assert_array_almost_equal
    assert_array_compare(compare, x, y, err_msg=err_msg, verbose=verbose,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py", line 840, in assert_array_compare
    raise AssertionError(msg)
AssertionError: 
Arrays are not almost equal to 6 decimals

Mismatched elements: 1 / 3 (33.3%)
Max absolute difference: 1
Max relative difference: 0.25
 x: array([[1, 2, 3]])
 y: array([[1, 2, 4]])
```

While test arrays may be small, production arrays are often quite large.  This statistical style of reporting is more useful than the more detailed differences of the `unittest` method.

Note what the `numpy` test has done.  I gave it lists, which it converted to `numpy` arrays.  That's common practice in `numpy`. It's much simpler to write code that converts the inputs into a 'standard' type at the start, rather than trying to account for different behaviors through out the code.  For what it's worth, `numpy` has a perfectly good `tolist` method

```
In [322]: M.assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],np.array([1.,2.,3.]).tolist())
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to show the failure!

```
In [1]: import unittest
   ...: unittest.TestCase().assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],np.array([1.,2.,3.]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-fb3ef7cd88ef>", line 2, in <module>
    unittest.TestCase().assertSequenceEqual([1,2,3],np.array([1.,2.,3.]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 1043, in assertSequenceEqual
    if seq1 == seq2:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The method uses `if seq1 == seq2:`.   It doesn't have a special case for `seq1 == seq2` results that are boolean arrays.  It's a simple `if` statement.  The ValueError is raised by `numpy` when an array (with more than one element) is used in a Python context that expects a scalar boolean value, such as an `if`.

`numpy` has its own testing utilities, such as https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_equal.html

Your first array is integer dtype, the second float.  Should they be equal or not?  Why?  We recommend an `allclose` test for floats.

### single element arrays

```
In [46]: unittest.TestCase().assertSequenceEqual([1],np.array([1.]))
In [47]: unittest.TestCase().assertSequenceEqual([1],np.array([3.]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-47-049a26b28f34>", line 1, in <module>
    unittest.TestCase().assertSequenceEqual([1],np.array([3.]))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 1100, in assertSequenceEqual
    self.fail(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/unittest/case.py", line 753, in fail
    raise self.failureException(msg)
AssertionError: Sequences differ: [1] != array([3.])

First differing element 0:
1
3.0

- [1]
+ array([3.])
```

Answer (score 0):

numpy provides `numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal` and other testing methods to be used with unittest (and other testing frameworks). pandas provides `pandas.testing.assert_series_equal`, and so on.

So, it is third party libraries that implement support for a standard library, and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

> assertSequenceEqual(first, second, msg=None, seq_type=None)¶ Tests
> that two sequences are equal. If a seq_type is supplied, both first
> and second must be instances of seq_type or a failure will be raised.
> If the sequences are different an error message is constructed that
> shows the difference between the two. This method is not called
> directly by assertEqual(), but it’s used to implement
> assertListEqual() and assertTupleEqual().

Also the numpy function follows too.